# WCF deployment to azure entity framework methods returning exception

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, entity-framework, azure

I am developing WCF for a Windows Phone Application.

The database is MySQL, hence I made use of ADO.net entity framework to access the data.
It works fine on the local environment.

However, when I deploy them to azure using package instance, I get an exception for the methods utilizing the entity framework. Other methods that don't require database data returns values fine like : getHello()

I'm using the latest mysql connector for visual studio.

For testing, I make use of the WCFTestClient.exe. This is what returns me when I invoke the method:

```
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.getUUser(Int32 userUid)
   at Service1Client.getUUser(Int32 userUid)
```

The service is **http://unifiqsvc.cloudapp.net/Service.svc**

Methods I am trying to fix are:

getUUser() - Enter any integer 1 to 3 will return an account detail

updateLoc() - Enter any integers in uid, lat, longit (Insert record)

You are welcome to access the service to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I made sure MySQL.Data.dll, MySQL.Web.dll, MySQL.Data.Entity.dll, and System.Data.Entity.dll System.Data.Entity.Design System.Data.dll are all being copied local (Copy Local is set to true)

Add the following to your web.config file:

```
  <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
        Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```